# Loading images and eval() in tensorflow are super slow

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
X = []
filelist = gfile.ListDirectory(path_imgs)

for filename in filelist:
    path_filename = path_imgs + filename
        image_file = file_io.FileIO(path_filename,'rb')
        image_raw = image_file.read()

        img = tf.image.decode_image(image_raw)
        img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
        img = tf.image.resize_image_with_pad(img, img_size, img_size, method=1).eval(session=tf.Session())
        X.append(img)


imgs = np.array(X)
```

Tried some things with session, but didn't work. Probably it should be handled differently, but I don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Yes, I want to train ANN to segment objects in images.

There are folders with images and their masks. Size is 1000s, and could be 10s of 1000s.

I need single numpy array of images, which will be saved, and used later as dataset for model training.

Comment: Please add more details about what you exactly want, because there are different solutions for different purposes. How large is each image? And how many images you are dealing with? Do you just want to get multiple numpy arrays of images in a folder? (If that is the case, you don't even need to use tensorflow) Do you want to do some machine learning stuff (e.g. convolution neural network) on those images ?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
def getImageData(fileNameList):
    imageData=[]
    for fn in fileNameList:        
        testImage = Image.open(fn)
        testImage.show() 
        imageData.append(np.array(testImage))
    return np.array(imageData,dtype=np.float32)

imageFn=("dog.png",)
imageData=getImageData(imageFn)
```

you must import something:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image    
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Sorry, but this ain't gonna work. Biggest resource hog here is TF session and eval(), which are not mentioned in your code.